# Visual Studio 2019 is it possible to output file to upper case?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Is it possible to output a file always with upper case file name? For example if I use the effect compiler:

[image]

Can I make my output .cso files always to upper case, no matter in the (Filename) is lower or upper case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, you can use a subset of the .NET functions in MSBUILD as described here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/property-functions?view=vs-2019

In your case this should work:

```
$(OutDir)shaders/$([System.String]::Copy('%(Filename)').ToUpper()).cso
```

Just make sure you delete existing files with the same name that are partially lower-case, since MSBUILD by default will just overwrite that file instead of creating a new one.